# How do you concatenate an integer and letter so that the result remains an integer

Tags: python, string, integer, python-2.x

The issue is that I have an integer variable (e.g. X = 123) that needs to be concatenated with the string (e.g. "L") and still remain an "integer." The reason is that the id I'm passing to an api call needs the id to be in the following format:

```
10150247729954L
```

Notice that because there are no quotes, it is not a string. I'm assuming it's still an integer variable, as it's purple like other numbers in sublime.

For example, how do I turn this integer into the desired format:

```
integer = 10150247729954 
desired_integer = 10150247729954L
```

This is what I've tried which has resulted in errors:

```
 int('10150247881525L')
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10150247881525L'
```

When I just try to push the string through the API Call I get:

```
 TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`L` is *not* part of the numeric value.

Rather, *in Python 2.x*, it is [*part of a integer literal*](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals) as understood by the Python parser - it results in a `long` value vs an `int` value, if it were not suffixed. (Python will automatically up-promote larger integer literals to long values as required, the `L` is optional in this case.)

The *repr* of `long` will also be suffixed with `L`, where there is no suffix for `int` values.

Use `long(anInt)` to force explicit conversion from `int` to `long`.

---

Python 3 [removes the "L" notation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals) as it effectively combines `long/int` (ref. [integer changes](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers)).

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you want to convert an integer into a [long integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_integer#Long_integer).  This can be done with the [`long`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#long) built-in:

```
>>> integer = 10150247729954
>>> long(integer)
10150247729954L
>>>
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm a bit confused on what exactly is a "long integer" and why does it involve appending a letter L to the integer?

Comment: Long integers are integers larger than the machine's native word size, pythons long integers supports arbitrary size integer while int is limited to the machine's word size. The distinction between int and long is now irrelevant in modern python code because now python transparently convert between int and long as necessary, and in fact the L suffix has been removed in Python 3.